# java convert string pattern to date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

how to convert string to date in java , i have such string that i get from database

> Aug 12, 2011, 8:17:46 PM

i used different **SimpleDateFormat** but i can't convert it , i am getting

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:

here is a sample of my code :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, YYYY, 'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    try{
        Date date = sdf.parse("Aug 12, 2011, 8:17:46 PM");
        System.out.println(date);
    }
    catch(Exception pe){
        System.out.println(pe);
    }
```

Comment: Your pattern says there has to be a `T` before the hour, and that the hour is expressed as a 24-hour value, and that you've got milliseconds but no am/pm specifier. Your value doesn't follow that at all. I'd also strongly recommend using the new java.time package instead of java.util.Date and java.text.SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: The pattern does not match the format of the `String`: The `String` does not have a `T`, so you don't have to escape one in your pattern. The time of day is obviously in 12h format, so you shouldn't make the pattern consider 24h format and your pattern expects fractions of second, but the `String` does not provide any. I recommend a deep dive into the docs of `java.time`, or at least one into the docs of `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy, hh:mm:ss a");`

Answer (score 0):

i managed to make it work by using

> DateTimeFormatter